# Firebase limit_to_last(1) doesn't work as expected

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data in firebase that is recording temperature like the following:
[image]

I will eventually have a number of weeks, the key starts at `1`, next week the key will be `2` then `3` etc etc
I wanted to write a query that gives me the data from the last week (The week with the highest numbered key)

I have this line of code in a python script:

```
rtn = root.child('bedroom').child('weeks').order_by_key().limit_to_last(1).get()
print(rtn)
```

This is what is printed out:

```
[None, {'date_time': '2018-06-08 19:38:41.634010', 'temperature': '21'}]
```

Why is `None` at the start of the array? Do I assume it is always here? I want to use the data in the second location of the array. But if it isn't always in the second location of the array my code will then break. I thought that query would return an array of size 1.
I think when I was testing I did see the array only being 1 element in size with the json structure as the first element but I cannot confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

When you use numeric keys (like you do), Firebase may interpret your data as an array. To learn more about this, read [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

If this array coercion is a problem for your app, I recommend prefixing the number with a fixed string, e.g. `"week_1`" or even better `"week_01` (since that may you can filter on ranges of weeks).

Comment: I just inserted weeks `1` to `10` for testing, when i print the last now i get `OrderedDict([('10', {'temperature': '21', 'date_time': '2018-06-08 20:21:37.413075'})])`, edit: to confirm, anything above `1` seems to work :/